# How to convert tabs into side menus in Ionic Framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Depends on config value(tabs or side menus), show the tabs or side menus.  how to switch from tabs to side menus and vice versa. How to do this? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just make two diferent templates and chosing one or another depending of the configuration.